# How to replace an element in an array without changing the other elements?

Tags: javascript

If I have this array `['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June']`. How to replace `'April'` with `'newVal'` and keep all other elements unchanged.
I tried

```
const months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(3, 1, 'newVal');
console.log(months);
```

I want it to return `['Jan', 'March', 'newVal', 'June']`
but it returns `["Jan", "March", "April", "newVal"]`

Comment: months[2] = "newVal"

Comment: Index of arrays starts with `0`. So the index should be `2`

Comment: what do you mean with "*without touching*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not assign directly?

```js
const
    months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];

months[2] = 'newVal';

console.log(months);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
a.splice(2,1,"newVal")
```

It deletes 1 element at position 2 and adds the new value "newVal"

Answer (score 2):

You could first find the [Arrray.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) some *"string"*, than you can directly replace it:

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const idx = arr.indexOf("c");       // 0..N or -1 if not found

// Make sure the index is found, than replace it
if (idx > -1) arr.splice(idx, 1, "newVal");
```

A nifty reusable function:

```js
const replaceInArray = (arr, oldVal, newVal) => {
  const idx = arr.indexOf(oldVal);
  if (idx > -1) arr.splice(idx, 1, newVal);
};



const months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
replaceInArray(months, "April", "newVal");
console.log(months)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the value you want to replace (ie: you always want to replace 'April') :

```
months[months.indexOf("April")] = 'newVal';
```

Answer (score 1):

Always remember that the first index of an array is always 0, so just do this instead :

```
months.splice(2,1,"newVal")
```

Answer (score 1):

*The function which you used was correct but **You mistook the index value of element `april` of the array `months`***

**The correct index value of april is 2**

*So your code will be like this*

```js
const months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(2, 1, 'newVal');
console.log(months);
```